# How to run another node.js script and then kill it

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I want my testing script to be able to run my server and then kill it at the end of testing. In fact I will probably want to do this mulitple times in the testing script. I tired `exec` with shelljs. But that seems to me from running any commands after I start my server for testing it also seems like it would be hard to find the sever to kill it after starting it (especially on different OSes). How might I do such a thing?

Comment: Can you add the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

On different OS you will need to find processId to kill it. This is tedious and not recommended process.

Use a wrapper around like pm2 or nodemon for servers.
In testing case you can make use of process.exit(0) and expose it in your make code.